# Enviar comando PHP via Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Existe como enviar um comando PHP via Ajax?

Por exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: '<?php echo "teste"; ?>',
        success: function(r) {
         $('body').html(r);
    }
});
```

No caso, ainda estou estudando Ajax, eu não entendi muito bem, eu fiz esse codigo de exemplo, mas por exemplo, o que ele faz?

Ele envia o que tem no `data:` pra url index.php ou ele pega o conteúdo de index.php?

Se a resposta for a segunda, então pra que serve o data no ajax?

Mas voltando a minha pergunta, o que realmente queria saber é se tem como, enviar comando PHP via Ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Para entender melhor o funcionamento do ajax, vamos quebrar seu código em partes:**

Aqui seu código está dizendo que quer usar o ajax para enviar e/ou receber dados de outra página de forma assíncrona:

```
$.ajax({

});
```

O `url` determina a URI do qual ele vai fazer a requisição:

```
url: 'index.php',
```

O `type` especifica o tipo da requisição, ou seja, ele fala se os dados vão ser enviados em forma de `GET` ou `POST`:

```
type: 'POST',
```

O `data` é as informações a serem enviadas para a url da requisição, é comum que dê "nome aos bois":

```
data: { teste: '<?php echo "teste"; ?>' },
```

O `success` decide o que deve fazer caso a requisição seja um sucesso, o parâmetro que ele recebe é os dados retornados da página:

```
success: function(r) {
     $('body').html(r);
}
```

---

**E como executar o código php enviado pelo ajax?**

Considerando que você deu um nome para os dados enviados, você pode utilizar o eval para isso:

```
eval($_POST['teste']);
```

***Cuidado! O `eval` pode trazer sérias invulnerabilidades ao seus sistema, principalmente quando o client-side está envolvido!***

> Veja mais na [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) do AJAX
>   e na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.eval.php) do eval

Comment: Eu usar um comando do PHP direto em Ajax não tem como né? Por exemplo, sem precisar mexer no arquivo .php

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Você quer enviar o resultado do comando, ou o comando para ser executado?

Comment: no caso, ja executar o comando. Acho que isso não tem como né? Por exemplo, enviar um echo e ele executar automaticamente.

Comment: Tem sim, é exatamente da forma que você já está fazendo. Mas o arquivo em que o ajax está deve ser `.php`.

Comment: Oi Francisco. Acho que esbarrei na tela do celular e causei um -1 sem querer na sua resposta. Só que agora o sistema só deixa retirar se a resposta for editada. Não quer aproveitar e colocar um alerta de perigo na parte que fala do eval? ;)

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Tem algo muito estranho nisso que você está dizendo. Por ajax você vai sempre transmitir texto, como valores de campos (ou um arquivo, no caso de upload). No máximo você pode enviar código PHP (como texto) e executar com eval como o Francisco mostrou. Mas em 99.99999% dos casos isso é desnecessário, e pode ser extremamente arriscado em termos de segurança.

Comment: Eu vi, entendi agora. Ele envia tipo uma "url", um por exemplo, ?texto=asdas perguntei se dava por isso mesmo, pôs estava tentando enviar algo do tipo pro meu servidor e não sabia como aquilo chegava la.[

Comment: @bfavaretto Já editei a resposta.

Comment: @Lucas Se você mudar o método de POST para GET no código, os dados são enviados na URL no formato que você mencionou. Com post é parecido, mas não é na URL e sim no corpo da requisição HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

O que você por em `data` é o que vai ser enviado pro arquivo que você colocar em `url`, no seu caso é o `index.php`, no seu código, você estaria passando a string "teste" pro `index.php`.

Passar código `PHP` misturado com Ajax funciona, **porem** seu arquivo tem que ter a extensão .php e seu código ajax tem que estar envolto pelas tags `<script></script>`.

Exemplo funcional (dentro de um arquivo nome.php):

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: '<?php echo "teste"; ?>',  
            success: function(r) {
                $('body').html(r + '<?php echo "código php" ?>');
            },
            error: function(r){
                alert('deu erro');
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

essa opção 'data' do ajax serve para vc passar parametros ou valores que vão ser encapsulados no corpo da requisição e podem ser usados na url que vc está chamando.
 Por exemplo, imagine um ajax que pegue os dados de um usuario específico, vc pode passar pelo data o id desse usuario para o server saber o usuario e retornar para você esses dados. Exemplo de data:

```
$.ajax({                    
  url: 'index.php',     
  type: 'GET',
  data : {
    id_usuario : '1' // vc pode pegar esse id_usuario dentro do index.php
  },             
  success: function(data)         
  {
    // etc...
  } 
});
```

Já o retorno da requisição que no caso é o seu index.php, fica no success.

```
success: function(r) {
         $('body').html(r);
```

No caso o retorno do index.php esta dentro da variavel r e dentro da function do success vc pode trata-la ou fazer o que você precisar

Answer (score 0):

Você pode enviar parâmetros(via `data:{parametro1:"limpar", parametro2:"xxx"}`) para que os dados sejam tratados de diferentes formas no link da requisição. Existem várias formas de serializar esses dados/parâmetros. Por exemplo, para enviar um form inteiro para a requisição você pode enviar da seguinte forma:

```
data: $("#meu_form").serialize(),
```

E claro que existem formas mais complexas se uso do `AJAX` com controladores `MVC` e afins, mas creio que para inicio de estudos isso já esclarece um pouco.

Seu código envia o `data` com parâmetros `POST` para o `index.php` e seu retorno (dentro do `success`) é escrito na `tag` `body` da pagina (`$('body').html(r);`)

**url**

Uma string contendo o URL para o qual a solicitação é enviada.

**type**

Um alias para `method`. Você deve usar `type` se você estiver usando versões do jQuery antes de 1.9.0.

**data**

Tipo: PlainObject ou String ou Array
São definidos os dados a serem enviados para o servidor. Ele é convertido em uma seqüência de consulta, se ainda não for uma string. É anexado à url para pedidos GET. O objeto deve ser pares de chave / valor. Se o valor for uma matriz, jQuery serializa vários valores com a mesma chave com base no valor da configuração tradicional.

Fonte e leitura complementar:

> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/